# How to build ROS2 based application from outside of workspace

Tags: cmake, ros, ros2

I created a qt application which can be build by cmake. My application uses some ros2 service so I need to build it with ros. For that I need to put my code under ros2_ws/src/. I want to avoid this thing. I want to build by application from any folder ( without putting under ros2_wc) with ament tool. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that, you need to build ROS2 as usual, and source the following script:

```
. install/local_setup.bash
```

Then you can call your build command using ament from the directory you want.

```
cd <dir>
ament build --force-cmake-configure ...
```

Answer (score 0):

## For those who are using the new ros2 build tool: colcon

You can keep your own *~/ros2_ws*, and put the QT application to another `~/ros2_overlay_ws`.

For example, if your new QT application depends on some service or msg located in the original `~/ros2_ws`, you could go to `~/ros2_ws` and run `colcon build`. 
After compile finished, please remember to import and re-index your packages by the following command: `source ~/ros2_ws/install/setup.bash`. This will re-index your ros2 packages at current terminal.

Now go to `~/ros2_overlay_ws/` and put your QT application to `~/ros2_overlay_ws/src` and then run `colcon build`. colcon will find your indexed package and add them to your dependency.